# memset error in iPad app

Tags: objective-c, c

Hi Im currently building an iPad app. I was using the memset() as below but every tine          it runs I get a bad access error?

```
 arrayPointer = malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
memset(arrayPointer, 0, sizeof(int)* size); //sets all the values in the array to 0
```

Cheers

Comment: Make sure `size` is correct, and that `malloc` doesn't return `NULL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `calloc()` it basically does the same as `malloc()` but also sets all bits to 0 in the allocated memory. It is also suited well for array initializations. For your example:

```
arrayPointer = calloc(sizeof(int), size);
```

**EDIT:** You should consider inspecting the returned pointer. `NULL` will be returned, when your memory allocation was erroneous.